# When inserting a tuple into a table in SQL, does the order of the attributes in the schema matter?

Tags: sql, database-schema

ie. if Students(id,name,major,gpa) is the schema, are the following 2 SQL queries valid?

```
INSERT
INTO Students(id,name,major,gpa)
VALUES (123, Joe, CPSC, 3.0)

INSERT
INTO Students(name,id,major,gpa)
VALUES (Mike, 505, CPSC, 4.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes both of the query are correct. And the Values will insert to the column in whatever format your INSERT INTO t_Tablename(column1,column2) is made.

Just to make a check you can do (Assume **id** is **int** and **Name** is **varchar**)

```
INSERT INTO Students(id, Name)
VALUES("testString", 1)
```

which will give you an error, since you're trying to insert a string value to **id** which accepts an int and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two following queries are Valid. Since you keep the order of your attributes values as described in Students(column1,column2), the query will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the order in the `INTO` expression equates to the order in the `VALUES` expression, that is all that is required.  The column list in the `INTO` expression determines both which columns you're specifying values for and the order the values will appear in the `VALUES` expression.  The first column gets the first value, the second gets the second value, and so on.

If you neglect to specify the column list in the `INTO` expression, most RDBMSs will assume that the columns in the `VALUES` expression are in the ordinal order of columns in the table itself.  That is, if you do this:

```
INSERT INTO Students
VALUES (123, Joe, CPSC, 3.0)
```

Then you better have done something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (id int, name varchar(30), major varchar(30), gpa numeric(3,2))
```

That's the only time that the order of columns in the table itself actually matters to an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Good comprehensive explanation.